# MVC SelectList - how to feed it from a generic array of objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist

Is there a common way to feed the SelectList object from a list of objects? I am very hesitant to return SelectList from my database class as it means that it will be coupled with MVC...

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
@model MvcProject.Models.FooModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFooId, 
                      new SelectList(Model.Foos, "Id", "Name"),
                      "-- Select Foo --")
```

With this as your model:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public int SelectedFooId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what about my data access layer? Do I manually convert DataTable(which is what our custom class I have to use returns) to an object that implements IEnumerable?

Comment: @sarsnake can you post an example of your data object? Ideally, you would have a business layer that already handles this abstraction.

Comment: @sarsnake not necessarily, a `DataRowCollection` is an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` so it is possible to do it directly too, but it is bad design.